# Traces of Celtic in modern German?

Tags: history

I read on Wikipedia that Germanic people most likely originated from what today is Denmark, and expanded from there, displacing and possibly intermingling with the older Celtic populations.

Are there linguistic traces of this, *e.g.* words of Celtic origin that trace back to that time? Linguists can reconstruct the Proto-Indo-European language, which is much more ancient, so presumably tracing any Celtic influences is doable.

Comment: Most of the linguistic traces of the Celtic languages still present today in German can be found in place names and other geographic terminology, and in dialects.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are lots of remnants that can be traced back to Celtic languages in German - Especially in place names and names of rivers (*Rhein*, *Main*, *Lech*, *Inn*, even *Donau*). A typical example could be place names in southern Germany that start on "Kräh-" (like *Krähbühl*, for example) and don't normally trace back to the birds, but rather to the Celtic *craig* (rock).

But there are also just "normal" words that can be traced back to Celtic, like

- **Amt** - *ambactos* - "office" or "charge"
- **Apfel** - *afal*(?) - "apple"
- **Eibe** - *eburo* - "yew"
- **Beil** - *bitlon* - "hatchet"
- **Eisen** - *isarnon* - "iron"
- **Geisel** - *gistlos* - "hostage"
- **Glocke** - *cloccos* - "bell"
- **Leder** - *letro* - "leather"
- **Leinen** - *linno* - "linnen"

Some of them made it into today's English as well, probably from the same Celtic roots. From a lot of these terms it is not always easy to trace them *directly* to Celtic origin or whether they have to be treated as "re-imports" from other languages.

Obviously, there are Celtic terms like *Menhir* and *Dolmen* that are used for the same thing in German - I wouldn't consider them as direct holdovers of Celtic in German, however.

Wikipedia has a [page](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keltische_Sprachen#Ortsnamen) of Celtic remnants in various European languages, including the interesting claim the 20-based number system in French was actually of Celtic origin.

Comment: Could you share your sources, too?

Comment: Looks like a partial alphabetical listing, TBH.

Comment: @MaxB you seem to try to tell me something, but I don’t get it...

Comment: The words you listed look like they were taken from some alphabetically sorted list, but they only go from A to L.

Comment: They are *examples* pulled from various sources, and I didn't bother to sort them alphabetically. I'm sorry, I have no exhaustive list.

Comment: I have a suspicion that some of these are not of Celtic origin, but the Celtic and Germanic words have the same root. E.g. the precursor to *apple* seems to already exist in Proto-Germanic.

Answer (score 1):

Ja. *Hans Ulrich Schmid* (Einführung in die deutsche Sprachgeschichte, 3. Auflage 2017, S. 248) verweist auf **zwei Sach- und Wortbereiche**, in denen Lexeme aus den keltischen Sprachen durch die Germanen übernommen wurden.

> - **Technik:** Die Kelten der Antike waren in der Metallgewinnung und 
>     -verarbeitung wesentlich weiter fortgeschritten als die Germanen [...] Das fand seinen Niederschlag in einer Reihe von Wörtern,
>     die zusammen mit der Sache ins Germanische übernommen wurden und noch 
>     in heutigen germanischen Sprachen vorhanden sind. Neuhochdeutsch *Eisen*
>     beispielsweise geht über althochdeutsch *īsan* zurück auf germanisch **īsarn* [...] Zugrunde liegt
>     wohl ein keltisches Wort mit der Bedeutung ›Brust‹. Dem englischen
>     *lead* ›Blei‹ entspricht deutsch *Lot* (davon abgeleitet *löten*). Beides weist zurück auf ein urgermanisches Grundwort, das aus dem Keltischen
>     übernommen worden ist.
> - **Herrschaft und Verwaltung:** Die Kelten [...] verfügten auch über eine effektivere Sozialordnung [als die Germanen]. Aus dem Keltischen
>     stammt die ganze Wortsippe um neuhochdeutsch *Reich* und *reich*, zu der auch
>     das Namenssegment in *Fried-rich*, *Hein-rich* usw. gehört [...],
>     ebenso das Wort *Amt*. Neuhochdeutsch *Zaun* geht
>     [...] zurück auf germanisch **tūnaz*, das ›eingefriedeter Platz‹ bedeutet
>     haben muss. Grundlage dafür war wiederum keltisches *dūnos* [...]

Es ist im Allgeneinen allerdings nicht so leicht, Wörter etymologisch auf keltische Sprachen zurückzuführen. Siehe hierzu *Elmar Seebold*, The lexicon of Germanic, in: Klein/Joseph/Fritz, Handbook of Comparative and Historical Indo-European Linguistics, Band 2, 2017, S. 974-985, hier S. 981:

> Connections to the Celtic languages are very complex: **a portion of the**
>   **Germanic-Celtic etymologies are certainly due to their joint**
>   **Indo-European heritage**, while just as surely another part comprises
>   borrowed words (well attested in the lexical fields of *Amt* and
>   *Reich/reich*); but **in many cases it cannot be decided which of the two**
>   **options is correct**. Further complicating matters, an etymology can
>   sometimes be due to both factors, as when an Indo-European root or
>   form inherited by both branches has been subject to a special
>   development in Celtic, and Germanic has applied that development to
>   its native form.